# In Microsoft Test Manager, what is the best way to copy test cases that allows modification without changing original

Tags: mtm, tfs

In Microsoft Test Manager, via the Team Foundation Server Web Interface or the Stand Alone Test Manager 2017 Application, what is the best way to copy test case steps and copy test cases from one folder to another?

I want to be able to modify the copied test cases without it changing the original test case. is that possible?

Comment: Check this out, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/manual-test/mtm/copying-and-cloning-test-suites-and-test-cases;

Comment: you can post that as an answer @YuZhang

Comment: All good, hope it helped. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that, you need to create a clone of the test case, for that you may use the following steps

1. Go the test case and right click on it.
2. Click on **Create Copy and add to suite** option in the list.
3. Make the change if you want (Here you can modify test case independently without affecting other).
4. Click on **Save and Close**.
5. Now drag and drop that test case to other suites.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options to do this.

- When you enter a requirement in the “Requirements” module, you can link it to a test through “Test Coverage” sub module, provided a relevant test exists.
- When you write a test in the “Test Plan” module, you can link it to a requirement through “Req Coverage” sub module, provided a relevant requirement exists.